# Azure DevOps build agent does not have accesstokens in its tokencache

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to invoke rest api from within Azure DevOps build agent. For that I need bearertoken which I can get in my local machine with:

```
$accessToken = ((Get-AzContext).TokenCache.ReadItems() | Where { $_.TenantId -eq (Get-AzContext).Tenant } | Sort-Object -Property ExpiresOn -Descending)[0].AccessToken
```

However, on the build agent this never returns any tokens. Is there some other way I should try to get that token?

Comment: Do you get any error message in the build log?

Comment: No. I just do not get any tokens with that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and ideas. Answer was too simple to figure it out. I ripped most of the oneliner and now it works by only using:

```
$accessToken = ((Get-AzContext).TokenCache.ReadItems()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the 'Allow scripts to access the OAuth token' setting in the Agents settings?

[image]

This would be for builds and releases using the visual designer.

For YAML builds see [the predefined variable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=yaml). There are notes about using the "System.AccessToken" variable in a script. Essentially, you must explicitly map System.AccessToken into the pipeline using a variable. You can do this at the step or task level:

```
steps:
  - bash: echo This is a script that could use $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  - powershell: Write-Host "This is a script that could use $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```